# Not all codepaths return a value Error

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, return-value

I'm trying to create a simple program that finds the largest number in an array. I created the method in a separate class file, and then am just trying to create the object in the main page, and perform the method on an array that I created. I know this has something to do with me currently not returning a value on my method, but I'm still stuck. Sorry for the noob question, thanks in advance.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace FindMax
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Class1 MyClass = new Class1();

            int[] myArray = new int[] {1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 2, 2, 6, 3344, 223, 35, 5656, 2, 355543, 2222, 2355, 933433};

            int y = MyClass.FindMax(myArray);
            Console.WriteLine(y);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
}}}

using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace FindMax
{

    public class Class1
    {
        public int FindMax(int[] array) 
        {
            int temp = array[0];

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                 {
                if (array[i] > temp)
                {
                temp = array[i];
                }
                }}}}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a `return` statement in your `FindMax()` at all. That could be the start.

Comment: You need to add `return temp;` at the end of `Class1.FindMax`.

Comment: Yeah, the "return temp" after the second bracket in my class was what was holding me up. Thanks guys for helping me with my noob question!

Comment: @user2411290 - You should *Accept* one of the answers below.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing a return value of `int` above the last line of your `FindMax` function

The actual error is saying that your method expects an `int` to be returned, but your function never `return`s one.

```
public int FindMax(int[] array) 
    {
        int temp = array[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
         {
            if (array[i] > temp)
            {
            temp = array[i];
            }
         }
   return temp; //this
  }
```

alternatively, using LINQ, the following will do the same thing

```
var largest = array.OrderByDescending(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
```

As @MikeChristensen pointed out, `array.Max()` also works.

`var largest = array.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList()`
may interest you as it will give you a list will your entire list sorted from largest number to smallest

Comment: Well, if you're gonna use LINQ, then just `array.Max()`

Comment: @MikeChristensen = Hah! very nice, didn't know about that one

Answer (score 1):

The method signature:

```
public int FindMax(int[] array)
```

dictates that the method must return an `Int32`.  However, it does not return anything anywhere.

You need to add a return statement to the end of your method.  Perhaps you mean:

```
public int FindMax(int[] array) 
{
   int temp = array[0];

   for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
   {
      if (array[i] > temp)
      {
         temp = array[i];
      }
   }

   return temp; // <-- Add this
}
```

I'd also recommend checking to make sure the `array` parameter contains at least one element:

```
if (array == null || array.Length == 0)
   throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are simply never returning anything from your `FindMax` method in `Class1`. The way to fix it is to just add a return statement:

```
public int FindMax(int[] array)
{
    int temp = array[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        if (array[i] > temp)
            temp = array[i];

    return temp; // add the return statement here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a value

```
public class Class1
        {
            public int FindMax(int[] array) 
            {
                int temp = array[0];

                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                     {
                    if (array[i] > temp)
                    {
                    temp = array[i];
                    }
                    }

              return temp;
    }

    }

    }
```